# Trouble with referencing a javascript variable using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate a `div` element so that it changes its width.

The problem is that I want it to change its width to a variable that's stored in a `.js` file and I'm not sure how to get it to recognize it.

**My HTML code:**

```
<section style="width:100%;  height:120px;  clear:both;" >
    <section class="campaign_statistics" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;">

        <?php include('progress_chart.php'); ?>

    </section>
</section>
```

Uses include for that `PHP` file which contains:

```
if ($blog_id == 9)
    echo
    '
    <script>
    var percent = String(businessProgress.getPercent());
    document.write(businessProgress.toString());
    </script>
    '
;
```

I defined the variable percent to be referenced in jQuery. The `.js` file has an object that I made that stores some variables and I made getters to get their info when needed.

The `toString()` method:

```
this.toString = function(){
    var string = '<div class="campaign_progress" style="width:0%;"> <div class="campaign_percentage_bar">' + String(this.getPercent()) + '% Percent Unit Progress</div> <div class="campaign_dollars">$' + mySlice(this.getCurrent()) + '<span class="goal"> of $' + mySlice(this.getGoal()) + '</span></div></div>';
return string;
}
```

Basically builds the `div` element that I want to animate.

The width is set at `0%` and when my jquery is called in the header:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".campaign_percentage_bar").animate({width:String(percent)+'%')}, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

This is how I'm referencing that variable. I have the script calls in my header, so that all should be ok. If you can give any suggestions or if I need to clarify more or give more info, please comment.

Comment: Can you post a JSfiddle?

Comment: What are you trying to reference?  The variable percent?

Comment: Are you sure it's a string ?

Comment: width:String(percent)+'%') <<<< Extra Paren

Comment: @DavidL yes, that is the variable I'm trying to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".campaign_percentage_bar").animate({width:percent+'%'}, 5000);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. You were right about that extra parenthetical. I also changed the class to campaign_progress, the one I was using before wasn't correct. Thanks